# Vectored Exception Handling Process wide?

Tags: windows, process, seh

I know Windows seperatly builds a Structered Exception Handling Chain for each running thread within a process. I was wondering if with veh, the registered exception handler will be called process wide (no matter in what threat the exception occured) or was also registered on a per thread basis?

Comment: This is easy to just try by yourself, start a thread and have it dereference a null pointer.  Your callback runs on whatever thread triggered the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, vectored exception handlers are process wide.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681420(v=vs.85).aspx):

> An application can register a function to watch or handle all
>   exceptions for the application. Vectored handlers are not frame-based,
>   therefore, you can add a handler that will be called regardless of
>   where you are in a call frame.

[New Vectored Exception Handling in Windows XP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301714.aspx) by Matt Pietrek states:

> The handler list is not tied to any thread, and is global to the
>   process.